# Support for script_file in Nest library for Elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch, nest

I am using NEST v1.4.3 with Elasticsearch v1.5 and could not find anything in the ScriptFilterDescriptor which will translate to script_file in Elasticsearch.

Is there support for using scripts saved on disk with NEST library for Elasticsearch?

Comment: There is no support for `script_file` yet.

Answer (score 0):

By script_file, are you referring to the "file" parameter in the script request below :-

```
GET /_search
{
  "query":{
    "filtered":{
      "filter":{
        "script":{
          "file":"your_custom_script",
          "lang":"groovy",
          "params":{
            "shift":3
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

I have this same issue where I'm trying to use NEST to read from a script file written to disk.

This has been added recently: https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch-net/issues/1456